# Out of date AWS Tutorial; How to set up Elastic Beanstalk TVM Access & Private Keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, private-key, access-keys

On one of the last steps here on the Beanstalk TVM tutorial for mobile...

http://aws.amazon.com/code/7351543942956566

It goes through how to setup Access/Private keys at the end. However, there is no 'Edit Configuration' in the UI, only Save & Load options, and the load option doesn't have any fields for Access/Private keys. How do I set up those for a Beanstalk based TVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would indeed be nice if that tutorial could be updated for the new [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) UI - you can edit the configuration after clicking the cog icon in the top right of the *Software Configuration* tile in section *Web Tier* of tab *Configuration* within the dashboard (I currently seem to be unable to drag and drop a screenshot, sorry).

There you'll find section *Environment Properties* which lists all property names including `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY`.

Comment: Thanks! for the sake of anyone that comes after to speed up things it's the cog icon of the _Software Configuration_ tile that has the _Environment Properties_ and respective key fields.

Comment: @KurtWagner - so I managed to omit the most crucial piece of information after trying to list the entire path to those fields to make up for the lack of a screenshot ... -  sorry for that, and thanks for the comment, fixed now.